# Data for last week from Monday to Sunday- Available data is Datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column date time available in following format
'2022-02-28 08:30:08.000"

I would like run a SQL query to help me get data for last week from Monday to Sunday basis ongoing

Please help

Comment: OK, what is preventing you from doing that? Which part of that is your problem? What have you tried?

Comment: Hopefully your datetime column is of datatype datetime and therefore doesn't have a format.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results as formatted text.

Comment: I have been hardcoding date     CONVERT(DATE, created_dt) BETWEEN '2022-02-28' AND '2022-03-06'

 GROUP BY site_sid

Comment: OK i tried to search but let me do bit more effort now

Comment: You don't want to be applying a function (convert) to your column in your where clause - because it makes it unsargable i.e. unable to use indexes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to play around with **DATEPART**

Below script should return all data for current week.

```
-- below line will set Monday as first day of the week
set datefirst 1;
SELECT * 
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE DATEPART(ISOWK, YOUR_COLUMN) = DATEPART(ISOWK, GETDATE())
    AND DATEPART(YEAR, YOUR_COLUMN) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
```

Below should return data for whole previous week...

```
set datefirst 1;
SELECT * 
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE DATEPART(ISOWK, YOUR_COLUMN) = DATEPART(ISOWK, DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()))
    AND DATEPART(YEAR, YOUR_COLUMN) = DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Your second query fails for the week with January 1th, see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2bcb85c1702040549ada522781026d32)

Comment: edited, should work now.

Comment: should, yes, but does not, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b8bd871d19213e11902287fb55c6a6b4

Comment: HINT: the current week is 10, not 11, see: https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2022

Comment: oldest date you inserted is "2022-01-01" thus it did not return any data for December 2021

Comment: But, if that solves the problem, why do I only see 5 days?  (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4262267544b8519450e2e93ca299798d )

Comment: ah, yeah, you are right, my solution will not work when week is splitted between 2 years...

Comment: But you should also note: [Wrong week number using DATEPART in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220786/wrong-week-number-using-datepart-in-sql-server)